# Why this validation does not work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

`bail|required_if:other_field,2|date_format:"H:i"`

When "other_field" is equal to 1, `date_format:"H:i"` must not apply, but applies.

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bail|required_if:other_field,2,date_format:"H:i"
```

Comment: This is not valid Laravel Validation for required_if